# HP Pavillion 360. No wifi, trying to load wrong driver?

Tags: wireless

I got a new HP Pavilion 360, new boot of Ubuntu Studio's. Just like with  every Pavilion before, the wifi card can't be found.

I'm sorry, I'm sure this is already posted somewhere but im a DOS kid. I'm getting old and after about 5-10 minutes of reading it feels like my eyes are melting out of my head. Until I figure out how to reverse all my colors im physicaly unable to 
 go through all the forum pages.

I've installed the driver, it was accepted but TXT file does not say how to load driver. Right now my PC is trying to load iwlwifi-7265d-19 and - 18 when it should be loading 3169-14.

Am i missing a load command or is there a congif file that needs adjusted?

Installation of the firmware is simply:

% cp iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode /lib/firmware

You can now load the driver

```
[    2.128701] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    2.128704] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[    2.150845] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.151019] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.158125] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm

[    2.188003] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    2.189212] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.190149] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.267059] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 81
       serial: 08:d4:0c:98:c3:76
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-lowlatency firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
$ rfkill
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-62-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     4116E844336D79483D28F6F

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: The driver loads OK. The problem is different.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
sudo modrobe -r acer_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```